# WooCommerce RestAPI Get product by SKU (not ID!)

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to download a product by giving it the sku in the RestAPI.
I have tried it in the following two ways:

/wp-json/wc/v3/products?sku=’001023′?consumer_key=… …
Always return []

wp-json/wc/v3/products?filter[sku]=’001023′?consumer_key=… …
Gives me back all my products

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Comment: OK. 
Found the solution:
/wp-json/wc/v3/products?sku=001023&consumer_key=YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY&consumer_secret=YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET